# How to get a substring in awk

Tags: bash, awk, printf, substr

This is one line of the input file:

FOO BAR 0.40 0.20 0.40 0.50 0.60 0.80 0.50 0.50 0.50 -43.00 100010101101110101000111010

And an awk command that checks a certain position if it's a "1" or "0" at column 13 
Something like:

```
 awk -v values="${values}" '{if (substr($13,1,1)==1) printf values,$1,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13}' foo.txt > bar.txt
```

The values variable works, but i just want in the above example to check if the first bit if it is equal to "1".

**EDIT**

Ok, so I guess I wasn't very clear in my question. The "$13" in the substr method is in fact the bitstring. So this awk wants to pass all the lines in foo.txt that have a "1" at position "1" of the bitstring at column "$13". Hope this clarifies things.

**EDIT 2**

Ok, let me break it down real easy. The code above are examples, so the input line is one of MANY lines. So not all lines have a 1 at position 8. I've double checked to see if a certain position has both occurences, so that in any case I should get some output. Thing is that in all lines it doesn't find any "1"'s on the posistions that I choose, but when I say that it has to find a "0" then it returns me all lines.

Comment: Your awk command works for me based on your edited requirement. How does it not work for you? Are there fields after the 13th? If not you can print $0 which is the whole line (`printf values,$0`)

Comment: I could use $0, if not for the fact that i excluded $2 on purpose. So the sequence is $1,$3,$4 etc. I want to be able to say: if the 8th position of the bitstring(the 13th column in each line of foo.txt) is equal to "1" then append this line to bar.txt

Comment: Oops, I missed the missing $2. What do you get if you use `if (substr($13,8,1)==1) printf ...`? That should work.

Comment: strange thing is, if i say "if (substr($13,8,1)==1)" it gives me nothing, when i use "if (substr($13,8,1)==0)" it gives me everything. And this problem occurs on every position. 1 gives nothing, 0 gives me all.

Comment: 0 gives you all because position 8 is 0 and the `if` statement becomes true if you do `if (substr($13,8,1)==0` ! you are making it very confusing. show the output that you desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat file
FOO BAR 0.40 0.20 0.40 0.50 0.60 0.80 0.50 0.50 0.50 -43.00 100010101101110101000111010
FOO BAR 0.40 0.20 0.40 0.50 0.60 0.80 1.50 1.50 1.50 -42.00 100010111101110101000111010

$ awk 'substr($13,8,1)==1{ print "1->"$0 } substr($13,8,1)==0{ print "0->"$0 }' file
0->FOO BAR 0.40 0.20 0.40 0.50 0.60 0.80 0.50 0.50 0.50 -43.00 100010101101110101000111010
1->FOO BAR 0.40 0.20 0.40 0.50 0.60 0.80 1.50 1.50 1.50 -42.00 100010111101110101000111010
```

Comment: I want to be able to specify the position of the "1" or "0". Only the OP example used the first position.

Comment: show a valid example of your input file, and describe more clearly using that input file. I can't understand your problem. your substring statement in OP is correct if you are trying to pull the 1st character of the 13th field. why does it not work for you? if you want the 8th position of $13, then do `substr($13,8,1)==1`

Comment: i edited the OP. I am using this substr($13,8,1)==1, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: what doesn't seem to work ? position 8 of $13 is a 0 right? that's why it doesn't work since you are checking against 1.